# Scrolling issues on mac os

Tags: javascript, macos, trackpad

So I have write a script for my portfolio website to scroll to section by index. It works on every tested browser and smartphone but on a mac device it  does not work probably instead to scroll to the next sections it is going automatically to the second next section.

Hopefully someone can help me.

```
var anchorPoints = [];
var anchorLocation = [];
var anchorIndex = 0;
var waiting = false;
var canScroll = true;
var offset = 0

window.onload = function () {
    anchorPoints = document.getElementsByClassName("js-anchor");

    for (i = 0; i < anchorPoints.length; i++) {
        getLocation = anchorPoints[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        getLocation = getLocation.top - offset;

        anchorLocation.push(parseInt(getLocation));
    }
}

$(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    if (detectMobile() == true) {
        return;
    }
    if ((waiting || canScroll == false)) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();//prevent the default mousewheel scrolling
    var active = $('section.active');
    var delta = e.originalEvent.detail < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    waiting = true;
    if (delta < 0) {
        anchorIndex += 1;
        if (anchorIndex > (anchorPoints.length - 1)) {
            anchorIndex = 0;
        } 
        scrollTo({
            top: anchorLocation[anchorIndex],
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });

        console.log(anchorIndex);
        console.log('scrolling down');
    } else {
        anchorIndex -= 1;
        if (anchorIndex < 0) {
            anchorIndex = anchorPoints.length - 1;

        }
        scrollTo({
            top: anchorLocation[anchorIndex],
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
        console.log(anchorIndex);
        console.log('scrolling up');
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        waiting = false;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: "Somehow the link to codepen.io doesn't work, without https:// it does.": That's because when you enter the codepen link you get the error: "Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.". 

Please add a snippet of the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question.